# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:

Tags: java

I am using JDK 14 on Netbeans on Windows 10. Everything works fine in the IDE environment. However, when I try to compile and run a source file from the command prompt, I get the `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError`.

```
JAVA_HOME=c:\java\jdk14
```

The PATH and CLASSPATH in the system variables contain `JAVA_HOME\bin`, `JAVA_HOME\lib`.

If I issue java -version from the command prompt, in the JAVA_HOME directory, I get the following:

```
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

If I issue java -version from the JAVA_HOME\bin directory I get a different message listed below:

```
java version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I am not sure why? Please offer any advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that determines which version of Java is being run is which `java.exe` file is being run, which from the command line is solely determined by the `%PATH%` variable.

`JAVA_HOME` and `JDK_HOME` are typically used by wrappers that need to *find* the Java command on disk.  If you point directly to the java.exe file, they are not needed.   I would suggest prepending `C:\java\jdk14` to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you. It appeared that an older version of java.exe was installed at part of the Windows OS and reflected in the PATH system variable before the JAVA_HOME\bin

Comment: You probably have installed it in a browser way back.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have the path to a java binary of version 8 in the PATH as well and before the JAVA_HOME entries. You should be able to find out which `java` is used with the `where` command like `where java`. Or just put the JAVA_HOME entries at the very beginning of the PATH variable.